biblatex (verbose-trad2) titles in lowercase in citations and in bibliography
I am using the verbose-trad2 style for biblatex (xelatex). But this style does not allow me to have titles in lowercase. The title is always in uppercase for the initial letter in the footnote and in the bibliography. Exemple:

This is my option:
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2, backend=biber, autolang=hyphen, ibidpage=true, strict=true, hyperref=true, dashed=false, url=false, doi=false, isbn=false, eprint=false, citepages=omit, sorting=nyt, autopunct=false]{biblatex}

Thank you for your answer

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

So, for now Les Ficelles Du Métier : Comment Conduire Sa Recherche En Sciences Sociales is uppercase for the initial letter. I would like to show in lowcase Les ficelles du métier. Comment conduire sa recherche en sciences sociales

Sorry, i found. Because .bib file is in uppercase. Sorry about it. Have a nice day
